# how to create drag and drop in recyclerview without drag header and footer?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I created drag and drop in recylerview using ItemTouchHelper.Callback,it is working.But i have header and footer in recylerview i dont want to drag header and footer.how to solve this,this is my code

recylerviewActivity

```
 ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SwipeAndDrag(pick_up_mAdapter);
        ItemTouchHelper touchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

SwipeAndDrag.java

```
public class SwipeAndDrag extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private final ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter;
    private RouteInformation points;
    public SwipeAndDrag(ItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {

            return false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                          RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a dragArea or a button that starts the drag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your getMovementFlags method like this (tested it and it seems ok) :

```
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){
    if(viewHolder instanceof yourFooterOrHeaderViewholderClass){
        int dragFlags = 0; // then, they can't be dragged
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }else{ // if(viewHolder instanceof yourNormalItemViewHolderClass)
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }
}
```

Then, only your items should be drag&dropped, whereas your header and footer couldn't be manually moved.